# jquery selector for multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, selector

I have elements in my DOM with class="LiveVal:variablepart" and i would like to write a JQuery selector that works even if the elements have other classes on tom of the above. Eg. class="header LiveVal:varablepart" or class="LiveVal:varablepart header".

It works fro me if LiveVal is the first class with:

```
$('[class^=LiveVal:]').each(function ( intIndex ) { somefunction });
```

but obviously not if another class is before LiveVal.

In the function I need to extract the variable part. I planned to do like this:

```
theclass = $( this ).attr('class');
varpart = theclass.replace('\bLiveVal:(.+?)[\s]', '$1');
```

..but alas, it doesn't match. I've tested the regex on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ where it seems to work, but it doesn't in javascript !?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's worth noting that `LiveVal:ariablepart` is an invalid CSS class name.

Comment: @Jason It *is* an invalid CSS class name, but it is *not* an invalid part of a "class" attribute value.

Comment: @Pointy I suppose you could put *anything* as an attribute value. Still ugly IMO.

Comment: @Jason McCreary I agree, but for an application that's stuck with strict XHTML, there aren't too many good ways to do more interesting non-intrusive coding. In other words, if it's desirable for the markup to communicate name/value property information, then this class hack is one of the most concise ways to do it.  In an HTML5 world, the "data-foo" attributes are a better way to do it, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be somewhat faster to do this with an explicit filter:

```
 $("*").filter(function() { return /\bLiveVal:/.test(this.className); }).something();
```

It depends on whether the native "querySelectorAll" does the work, and does it quickly.  This also would avoid the "FooLiveVal" problem.

It's worth noting that in an HTML5 world, it might be better to use a "data-LiveVal" attribute to store that "variable part" information on your elements. Then you could just say:

```
$('[data-LiveVal]').something();
```

In the HTML, it'd look like this:

```
<div class='whatever' data-LiveVal='variable part'>
```

Since version 1.5, jQuery will *fetch* stuff in a "data-foo" attribute when you pass the tail of the attribute (the part after "data-") to the ".data()" method:

```
  var variablePart = $(this).data('LiveVal');
```

The ".data()" method will *not*, however, update the "data-foo" property when you store a new "variable part".

*edit* — if you want the *value* that's stuffed into the class after your property name prefix ("LivaVal:"), you can extract it like this:

```
  var rLiveVal = /\bLiveVal:(\S*)\b/;
  $('*').filter(function() { return rLiveVal.test(this.className); }).each(function() {
    var variablePart = rLiveVal.exec(this.className)[1];
    //
    // ... do something ...
    //
  });
```

(or some variation  on that theme).

Comment: I think this is quite an elegant solution, thats what I decided to go for. Cannot figure the performance relative to ihrbob's solution, but it shouldn't be critical.

Comment: What about the regex part? I guess I've got it wrong - I cannot use the $1 as a placeholder for what replace finds between the (), can I ?

Comment: Ah well that particular regex just does the filtering. You could re-use it if you want; I'll update the answer ...

Comment: You are a genious :o) you just saved my day - thanks a lot for the edit.

Answer (score 5):

This will check if a class name contains 'LiveVal:'

```
$('[class*=LiveVal:]').each(function ( intIndex ) { somefunction });
```

**EDIT**
did not realise you had that requirement (although a good one). You can do this instead: `$('[class^="LiveVal:"], [class*=" LiveVal:"]')`

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wY8Mh/

Comment: yes but it will also match class="NoLiveVal", if that should happen to exist, but a fair solution otherwise.

Comment: @TheRoadrunner, this is a good point. For your case this will not work.

Comment: @TheRoadrunner, you can use this and in the function check if it matches, if not, ignore it/filter it out.